# How to use/install client certificate in xamarin mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm developing a xamarin mobile application, and I'm trying to call the restful API to get the data. But the Restful API is using certificate-based authentication. In windows machine, we have certmgr where we can import the certificate and install it. Anyone knows how to usw this client certificate in mobile phones. Is it possible to install it?

Comment: what kind of certificate is it?

Comment: X.509 certificates. Actually the API verifies the certificate and validates based on the thumbprint stored in db.

Comment: @G.hakim he is asking about installing certificates. Certificates are not installed on Xamarin (and have NOTHING to do with it) but rather on iOS and Android, and surely not on Xamarin.Forms, so please don't edit tags further. Even Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android are wrong tags as this has nothing to do with code.

Comment: @IvanIčin even, in that case, the relevant tags would be Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS don't you think?  Or are you telling me native developers are gonna tell him how to do it using xamarin? as a xamarin user,  I would suggest him to use a web server! And what will they tell him I mean I am confused here

Comment: @G.hakim I think web server is a very good solution, that's what I answered below. As far as I can see installing on Android has nothing to do with code, while installing on iOS gets complicated and the app must also work to install certificate, so some code may be required... So maybe also Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android tags, I'll add them now.

Comment: Hi guys, you are right. It is nothing to do with xamarin development. But while testing the api hosted in the server will be looking for an x509 certificate. but how can install the certificate in android mobile atleast to test my xamarin app.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is done per platform not on Xamarin, those should be the answers:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html
- https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/installing-certificates-onto-android-devices/

It is a bit complicated on iOS and also you may not like that it is done per platform, but then there is always the third way - building your web server that will add the certificate to requests, it is frequently the right solution.